# How to select characters for a party and load in a different scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having trouble saving a party (like an RPG) and then recalling which team was saved.

I thought I could store the images/sprites as PlayersPref, but that doesn't work.

Here is what I am doing.  I have 5 character types (green, red, purple, orange  and blue).  Each type has 5 characters.  (25 total)

[image: screen where the character is selected and saved]

So you can see how when you select green at the top it pulls up the 5 options at the bottom.  A player has to select one from each group to build their team.  What I need to do is have it save that specific character, so that when I go to the gameplay mode or start the game up again it has those characters saved.

I would love some help on where to go from here.  I am truly lost.

OH WOW I got it to work!!! Here is how I did it.  I made a list of all the sprites in a multiarray, then when the button is clicked on to set the character it stores that `charactersNumber`.  When the code runs at `Start` it checks to see which `characterNumber` was set and then assigns the image.

```
public class CharacterManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Sprite[,] CharacterList;

    public Sprite Green0;
    public Sprite Green1;
    public Sprite Green2;
    public Sprite Green3;
    public Sprite Green4;
    public Sprite Red0;
    .
    .
    .

    public Image greenCharacterImage;
    public Image redCharacterImage;
    public Image purpleCharacterImage;
    public Image orangeCharacterImage;
    public Image blueCharacterImage;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        CharacterList = new Sprite[5, 5];
        CharacterList[0, 0] = Green0;
        CharacterList[0, 1] = Green1;
        CharacterList[0, 2] = Green2;
        CharacterList[0, 3] = Green3;
        CharacterList[0, 4] = Green4;
        CharacterList[1, 0] = Red0;
        .
        .
        .

        int greenChar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("GreenChar");
        greenCharacterImage.sprite = CharacterList[0, greenChar];

        int redChar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("RedChar");
        redCharacterImage.sprite = CharacterList[1, redChar];

        int purpleChar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PurpleChar");
        purpleCharacterImage.sprite = CharacterList[2, purpleChar];

        int orangeChar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("OrangeChar");
        orangeCharacterImage.sprite = CharacterList[3, orangeChar];

        int blueChar = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BlueChar");
        blueCharacterImage.sprite = CharacterList[4, blueChar];
    }
}
```

public class CharacterData : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public int characterNumber;

public void SetCharacterData()
{
   //sets a bunch of character data

    if (colorNumber == 0)
    {
        //sets the number for the character that was clicked on
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("GreenChar", characterNumber);
    }
    if (colorNumber == 1)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("RedChar", characterNumber);
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: **"Each type has 5 characters. (25 total)"** How are these saved in your Resources folder. What is your naming convention for them?

Comment: I don't currently have one, for the most part.  Layer1, Layer2 etc..

Comment: I am making a solution. I will also make naming convention since you don't have one.

Comment: @Programmer  I got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Even though you solved this problem, your solution is not efficient.

Instead of saving each value one by one and using `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` and `PlayerPrefs.SetInt` more than a dozen time, you could this once with Json. Simply put this whole thing into a class then convert it to json and save with `PlayerPrefs`.

Also, using strings to represent your colors is not right. `Enum` is the right data type to use here to represent your *character types (green, red, purple, orange and blue)*. You can also store the image names in the an `Enum` then use `Enum.ToString()` to convert it to string when you want to to load the Sprite.

When saved with the solution I have below, this is what the data looks like:

```
{"charactersTypes":1,"characters":[6,7,8,10,9]}
```

As, you can see, this is a very small data. To get the code below work, create a folder in your `Resources` folder and name it `Characters`. Place all your `25` character `Sprites` there.  Using the `CharacterManager` script:

**Creating and Saving**:

```
CharacterManager cm = new CharacterManager();
```

When player chooses color, get and set the chosen color

```
cm.charactersTypes = CharactersTypes.Green;
```

When player chooses character, get and set the chosen character(5)

```
cm.characters[0] = Characters.GreenMario;
cm.characters[1] = Characters.GreenLuigi;
cm.characters[2] = Characters.GreenPrincessPeach;
cm.characters[3] = Characters.GreenToad;
cm.characters[4] = Characters.GreenYoshi;
```

When Game exists(`OnDisable`), save the `CharacterManager` data.

```
cm.saveCharacter();
```

**Loading**:

Load saved data

```
CharacterManager loadedCM = CharacterManager.loadCharacter();
```

Check which color was saved with Enum(You can add more color checks)

```
if (loadedCM.charactersTypes == CharactersTypes.Blue)
{
    Debug.Log("Blue");
} if (loadedCM.charactersTypes == CharactersTypes.Green)
{
    Debug.Log("Green");
}
```

Get the 5 saved sprites

```
Sprite[] loadedSprites = loadedCM.getSavedSprites();
```

Assign loaded Sprites to your `Image` component

```
public Image[] image;
for (int i = 0; i < loadedSprites.Length; i++)
{
    image[i].sprite = loadedSprites[i];
}
```

**`CharacterManager` script**:

Create the `CharacterManager` script then put everything below inside it. This should get you started. Make sure to **replace** values in `enum Characters` with the names of your 25 `Sprite` that are placed in the `Assets\Resources\Characters` directory. This should work out of the box.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class CharacterManager
{
    public CharactersTypes charactersTypes = CharactersTypes.NONE;
    public Characters[] characters = new Characters[5];
    Sprite[] sprites = new Sprite[5];

    public CharacterManager()
    {
        charactersTypes = CharactersTypes.NONE;
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            characters[i] = Characters.NONE;
        }
    }

    //Save Character
    public void saveCharacter()
    {
        string charJsonInfo = JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(charJsonInfo))
            return;

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("SaveCharacter", charJsonInfo);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    //Load Character
    public static CharacterManager loadCharacter()
    {
        string charJsonInfo = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SaveCharacter");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(charJsonInfo))
            return null;

        CharacterManager characterManager = JsonUtility.FromJson<CharacterManager>(charJsonInfo);
        Debug.Log("Json: " + charJsonInfo);
        return characterManager;
    }

    public Sprite[] getSavedSprites()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (characters[i] != Characters.NONE)
            {
                sprites[i] = Resources.Load("Characters/" + characters[i].ToString(), typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
            }
        }
        return sprites;
    }
}

//5 Character Types[Colors]
public enum CharactersTypes
{
    NONE, Green, Red, Purple, Orange, Blue
}

//25 Characters[Names]
public enum Characters
{
    NONE,
    RedMario,
    RedLuigi,
    RedPrincessPeach,
    RedYoshi,
    RedToad,

    GreenMario,
    GreenLuigi,
    GreenPrincessPeach,
    GreenYoshi,
    GreenToad,

    ////Add Orange ,Purple Blue and Orange Sprite enums below
}
```

Comment: You used the Json.  That is the next thing I want to learn.  Thank you for taking the time to do this. I will implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to save the sprite to PlayerPref, but instead, save its path to it, and later if you want to restore it:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerSpritePath", "a/b/c");
var path = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerSpritePath");
Sprite s = Resource.Load<Sprite>(path);
```

Comment: I tried this method.  I ran into an issue trying to find the 'name' on the Sprite, when the button was pushed.